# How to ignore the request to the favicon.ico in ASP.NET Core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

> Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<RandomCounter>();

        services.AddTransient<ICounter>(provider =>
        {
            var counter = provider.GetService<RandomCounter>();
            return counter;
        });

        services.AddTransient<CounterService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<CounterMiddleware>();

    }
}
```

With each new request, the counter increases by 2. I would like the counter to increase by 1 with each new call. What should I do in this case? Or here I just need to add a condition with each new request:?

> Middleware:

```
 using Dependency.Services;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace Dependency
    {
        public class CounterMiddleware
        {
            private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
            private int i = 0;
    
            public CounterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                _next = next;
            }
    
            public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ICounter counter, CounterService counterService)
            {
                i++;
                httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Request {i}; Counter: {counter.Value}; Service: {counterService.Counter.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Just check that the request uri's path is not /favicon, if it is, don't increment your counter

Comment: I didn't think I needed to write the path to favicon.ico. It turns out that it is written to the address bar implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ICounter counter, CounterService counterService)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.HasValue && !httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/favicon.ico"))
        {
            i++;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync($"Request {i}; Counter: {counter.Value}; Service: {counterService.Counter.Value}");
        }

    }
```